# Insert character Just after particular character in string : Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Url string and i want to insert minus "-" just after equal to sign(=).
I have following string :-

```
http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=250
```

or

```
http://www.bdm.com/gm.php?id=2
```

And i want the following string :-

```
http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=-250
```

or

```
http://www.bdm.com/gm.php?id=-2
```

Please try to avoid to use index count because length is variable every time so position of equal to(=) will also be different every time.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it by replacing `=` with `=-`:

```
let s = "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=250"
let res = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("=", withString: "=-", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

This is slightly dangerous in case you have multiple equal signs in the string. A more precise approach would be locating the first (or the last) equal sign, and composing the resulting string manually:

```
let s : NSString = "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=250"
let p = s.rangeOfString("=")
if p.location != NSNotFound {
    let res : String = s.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(p, withString: "=-")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use replacing **=** with **=-**, by using **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString** concept

```
 let aString: String = "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=250"
    let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("=", withString: "=-")
    print(newString)
```

you get **output** like

[image]

Comment: quick reply, nice (y)

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLComponents` allows you to access and modify each part
of a URL selectively. Here an example how to replace
`show=<num>` by `show=<-num>` even in a list of multiple query items:

```
var urlString = "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?foo&show=250&bar=baz"

if var urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: urlString),
    var queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems {
    for (idx, query) in queryItems.enumerate() {
        if query.name == "show", let val = query.value, let num = Int(val) {
            queryItems[idx] = NSURLQueryItem(name: query.name, value: String(-num))
        }
    }
    urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
    urlString = urlComponents.string!
}

print(urlString) // http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?foo&show=-250&bar=baz
```

Comment: Nice one Martin, I had the same thoughts as you can see :)

Answer (score 2):

I know that you have a working solution now but I thought I'd chime in with something a bit more general.

If you want more control over which parameters to append a minus sign to, you should look into the `NSURLQueryItem` class (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLQueryItem)).

You separate the URL into components by using the `NSURLComponents` class (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLComponents)) and can then get access to the `queryItems` array.

So something like:

```
if let components = NSURLComponents(string: "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=250"),
   let queryItems = components.queryItems {

}
```

Will give you a URL, split into components from your string and you have the query items in an array. Now you are ready to look at the individual queryItems:

```
for item in queryItems where item.value != nil {
    //here you can check on the item.name 
    //and if that matches whatever you need, you can do your magic
}
```

So, a function that will just add a minus sign to all parameters and return a URL string from that could look something like this:

```
func addMinusToParameters(inURLString urlString: String) -> String? {
    guard let components = NSURLComponents(string: urlString),
          let queryItems = components.queryItems else {
        return nil
    }

    var minusItems = [NSURLQueryItem]()
    for item in queryItems where item.value != nil {
        minusItems.append(NSURLQueryItem(name: item.name, value: "-\(item.value!)"))
    }
    components.queryItems = minusItems
    guard let minusUrl = components.URL else {
        return nil
    }
    return minusUrl.absoluteString
}
```

And an example:

```
if let minusString = addMinusToParameters(inURLString: "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=250&id=23") {
    print(minusString) //gives you "http://www.corpebl.com/blog.php?show=-250&id=-23"
}
```

And yes, it might seem like more work but I think it is more flexible as well.

Hope you can use this.